# CkEditor: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I had a problem with CKEditor. When I use plugin BBCode and input a basic smiley ( ex: ":D" or ":(" like the first image ) then the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" appears in console log, and the editor become empty looks like the third image.

Althought I had inserted "config.extraPlugins = 'smiley';" in config.js, the error still happen.

The first image, I input a smiley.

Then i click "Source" button in the second image.

And click "Source" button again in third image, this is error.

Image 1st: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNbCY.jpg

Image 2nd: Miss

Image 3rd: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUNfZ.jpg

And here is my code

```js
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', { extraPlugins : 'bbcode' });
```

In a config.js:

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'smiley';
  config.language = 'vi';
  config.uiColor = '#eeeeee'; config.height = 300;
};
```

Comment: Would you please show us your code ?

Comment: CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', { extraPlugins : 'bbcode' });


In a config.js:
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.extraPlugins = 'smiley';
 config.language = 'vi';
 config.uiColor = '#eeeeee';
 config.height = 300;
};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are setting the editor configuration incorrectly. You are setting [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins) separately in two places and as a result, you are **overwriting** the first setting (from `config.js`) with your in-page configuration (set in `CKEDITOR.replace`) instead of **extending** it. You can read more about configuration loading order [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration-section-configuration-loading-order).

Your screenshot shows that there is no smiley button in the toolbar which means that this functionality is not enabled at all.

Note that [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins) accepts a list of all additional plugins that you want to enable, so if you want to use both `bbcode` and `smiley`, your configuration should include them in one declaration:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'bbcode,smiley';
```

Additionally, see the [BBCode Editing sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/bbcode.html) from CKEditor SDK for an example of how you can configure CKEditor to output BBCode, and also configure smilies. Scroll down to "Get Sample Source Code" to get the complete working code that is used to create the sample. Also check the [documentation for BBCode editing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_bbcode) for more information.